# Hotkey to generate runnable JAR in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, ide

Is there a hotkey to automatically/effortlessly generate a runnable JAR file from Eclipse? I need to do this regularly and it is time consuming to go through the rigmarole of the standard manual way.

Comment: Look at this http://www.codejava.net/ides/eclipse/how-to-create-jar-file-in-eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an [Ant buildfile](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-93_project_builder.htm).  It's a little time consuming the first time, but once you've made it, you can create your runnable JAR file with the click of a button (specifically the green button to the right of the run button on your toolbar).

Answer (score 1):

To gererate jar Quickly, I use **ant**
http://ant.apache.org/
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ant/ant_eclipse_integration.htm

I use it, for compilation, generate jar, move file, execute jar...
If it can help you